# I want to make whole website on https but a single url on http?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

i'm using this code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jobzshopz.com/$1 [R,L]
```

it redirects my all http urls to https but now i want to redirect my post with http remainning all pages with https..!

https://jobzshopz.com/find-online-bise-lahore-matric-9th-10th-ssc-result-2016/584
Beacuse i'm using frame in this post and https is no loading the frame. Because frame is from http protocol website..! Help me with this please.

Comment: don't use frames. Use `Curl` or a similar importing device rather than frames, or you can use a frame call to an *HTTPS* frame child.

Comment: I used this but this not working i'm acctually embeding a live page of another domain                                                                                   `code`<object data="[link](http://result.biselahore.com)" width="650" height="500"><embed src="[link](http://result.biselahore.com)" width="650" height="500"> </embed></object>`code`

Answer (score 1):

To exclude 
`/find-online-bise-lahore-matric-9th-10th-ssc-result-2016/584`
 uri from the rule, you can use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/find-online-bise-lahore-matric-9th-10th-ssc-result-2016/584 [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jobzshopz.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: When it comes from google it comes with https:// and it open with https but if try with http it redirect me to my home page

Comment: How does it redirect to homepage ?

Comment: I'm using plugin if page not found redirect to home page but if you help me with this if it comes with https redirect it to http

Comment: You need to use an additional rule to handle the post  url if it comes with `https` to redirect to http
 , add the following at top :


    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/find-online-bise-lahore-matric-9th-10th-ssc-result-2016/584 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://jobzshopz.com/$1 [R,L]` edit : this was not mentioned in your op